# Why the robot doesn't move in RVIZ?

Tags: ros

I am working now with the real robot which is turtlebot3 burger. As shown in the rqt_graph below, I've run my custom package which is Im adding the `ann3_publisher` node to be published to the `gmapping` package and run in the real robot.

[image: rqt_graph]

But when I move the robot, it seems that the robot in the rviz application is not moving at all. The map and the robot is there as shown in the figure below but the robot is not moving:

[image: map]

I try to run `rosrun rviz rviz` on the terminal and add one by one, there is a warning message appear as shown in the figure below

[image: terminal]

When I run the common package `roslaunch turtlebot3_slam turtlebot3_slam.launch slam_methods:=gmapping` it works and I dont have this problem. May I know why and how to solve this?

This is my custom turtlebot3_slam.launch file to subscribe the /scan_new3 topic.

```
<launch>
  <!-- Arguments -->
  <arg name="model" default="$(env TURTLEBOT3_MODEL)" doc="model type [burger, waffle, waffle_pi]"/>
  <arg name="configuration_basename" default="turtlebot3_lds_2d.lua"/>
  <arg name="set_base_frame" default="base_footprint"/>
  <arg name="set_odom_frame" default="odom"/>
  <arg name="set_map_frame"  default="map"/>
  <arg name="open_rviz" default="true"/>

  <!-- TurtleBot3 -->
  <include file="$(find turtlebot3_bringup)/launch/turtlebot3_remote.launch">
    <arg name="model" value="$(arg model)" />
  </include>

  <!-- Gmapping -->
  <node pkg="gmapping" type="slam_gmapping" name="turtlebot3_slam_gmapping" output="screen">
    <param name="base_frame" value="$(arg set_base_frame)"/>
    <param name="odom_frame" value="$(arg set_odom_frame)"/>
    <param name="map_frame"  value="$(arg set_map_frame)"/>
    <rosparam command="load" file="$(find turtlebot3_slam)/config/gmapping_params.yaml" />
    <remap from="/scan" to="/scan_new3"/>
  </node>

  <!-- rviz -->
  <group if="$(arg open_rviz)"> 
    <node pkg="rviz" type="rviz" name="rviz" required="true"
          args="-d $(find turtlebot3_slam)/rviz/turtlebot3_scan3.rviz"/>
  </group>
</launch>
```

Below is the tf_tree of the real robot. One more information is when I run in gazebo simulation. it works and the robot moves. But when I run in real world, the robot doesnt move in rviz application.

[image: tf_tree]

Comment: If I'm reading this correctly the `turtlebot3_slam.launch` file works correctly, but your file doesn't? Can you provide the launch file that doesn't work?

Comment: @BTables sorry I think all of my file that I launch is working. But when I run rviz, just the robot isnt move. Which file do you mean?

Comment: @BTables or you need me to share the launch `turtlebot3_slam.launch` that subscribe to `the scan_new3` topic?

Comment: This looks like a frame/transform issue. What frame_id is rviz using under the `global_options` tab over on the left left side?

Comment: the fixed frame is map @BTables

Comment: I don't see any `map` frame in your tf_tree, only `map3`. Try changing your rviz launch file arg to `args="-d $(find turtlebot3_slam)/rviz/turtlebot3_gmapping.rviz"/>`

Comment: @BTables I have uploaded my tf_tree of real robot in the question. it seems that there is a `map` frame. One more information is when I run in gazebo simulation it works, but when I run in real world, the robot doesnt move in rviz application.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237911/discussion-between-btables-and-amirulj).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have got the answer. It is because the sensor of the robot reading that there is obstacle around it but there isn't. You can see on the second figure, the sensor detect the walls in circle (green color) and build the walls around it. So the robot cannot move in rviz. When I eliminate that reading, the robot can move as usual in rviz