# Why gmapping package is not run in multiple robot in real robot (not simulation)?

Tags: ros

I have run this command from raspberry pi of the robot tb3_0 to run the `/tb3_0/turtlebot3_core` node

> pi@raspberrypi:~ $ ROS_NAMESPACE=tb3_0 roslaunch turtlebot3_bringup turtlebot3_robot.launch

And then I run `gmapping` package for tb3_0 robot in the pc terminal

> amirul@nmy-lab:~$ ROS_NAMESPACE=tb3_0 roslaunch turtlebot3_slam turtlebot3_gmapping.launch set_base_frame:=tb3_0/base_footprint set_odom_frame:=tb3_0/odom set_map_frame:=tb3_0/map

But the gmapping package show a warning message

> [ WARN] [1635496431.864557793]: MessageFilter [target=odom ]: Dropped 100.00% of messages so far. Please turn the [ros.gmapping.message_notifier] rosconsole logger to DEBUG for more information.

What I think is I didnt publish the `robot_state_publisher` node to the `/tb3_0/gmapping` node. How can I run the `robot_state_publisher` node in the tb3_0 ROSNAMESPACE? Thank you!

This is the rqt_graph of the running node
[image: rqt_graph]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on how you're launching `robot_state_publisher`. If using a launch file you can use the `ns` attribute to apply a namespace *to the node*. However, if you want to publish a namespaced transform you should use the `tf_prefix` param. Take the following example

```
<node name="robot_state_publisher" pkg="robot_state_publisher" type="robot_state_publisher">
    <param name="publish_frequency" value="50.0"/>
    <param name="tf_prefix" value="tb3_0" />
</node>
```

Comment: HI @BTables can you help me answer this question? https://stackoverflow.com/q/72360485/16594158